# Recreating aniamtion / side scroll slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to recreate a animation / side scroll effect. The effect is from https://elrond.com/#partners and its located in the partner section. The slow moving circles. I tried to recreate it, but after slamming my head against mine desk for the duration of the weekend I couldn't recreate it. So here I'm asking for some help.

I made a little code pen to show where I'm at now.

```
    .slide-wrapper{
  max-width: 800px; 
  height: 30vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  
  outline: red;
}

.slider{   
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  display:flex;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
  animation: scroll 15s infinite linear;  
}

.slider:last-child  .slide{
  background-color: steelblue;
  animation: scroll 13s infinite linear;
  margin-top: 5rem;  
}

.slide{  
  background-color:orangered;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin: 1rem 6rem;  
  
}

@keyframes scroll {  
  100%{transform: translateX(-66.6666%)}
}
```

https://codepen.io/tijmenjacobs/pen/LYxrvKq

My main questions are the following:

- How can I loop the animation? Now when the animation is done it teleports back to its original position and restarts.
- I was wondering how to position the circles. Should I handle JS to random assign the circles or should I hard code the location? Like they seem to do on the original.

Hope you guys could help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the example given by you, they have two `.slider` elements which are next to each other

Comment: To get continuous sliding you’ll need (at least) two copies, depending on how confident you are that one will be at least as wide as the viewport.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments! I update the Codepen but there is still a stutter. Any good ideas to fix it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired effect you need two of the same sliders next to eachother (*`slider-main` and `slider-copy` in the snippet*).

I used [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to make it easier to calculate offsets and whitespace. The offset between the slides is based on the amount per row (`--slides-per-row`). These are set within the HTML so you can easily reuse the slider somewhere else.

```css
/* Basic reset */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body > * + * {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

/* Slider styling */

.sliders {
  display: flex;
}

.slider {
  --slide-offset: calc(100vw / var(--slides-per-row, 4)); /* --slides-per-row is set via HTML and uses 4 if nothing is provided */
  --slide-size: 5rem;
  flex: 0 0 100vw;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
}

.slider-row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Offset every odd row */
.slider-row:nth-child(2n+1) {
  transform: translateX(
    calc((var(--slide-offset) / 2 + var(--slide-size) / 2) * -1)
  );
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.slide {
  width: var(--slide-size);
  height: var(--slide-size);
  margin: 0 0 0 var(--slide-offset);
  background: steelblue;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  /* Center content */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>4 slides per row</h2>
<div class='sliders' style='--slides-per-row: 4'>
  <div class='slider slider-main'>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>1</div>
      <div class='slide'>2</div>
      <div class='slide'>3</div>
      <div class='slide'>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>5</div>
      <div class='slide'>6</div>
      <div class='slide'>7</div>
      <div class='slide'>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='slider slider-copy'>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>1</div>
      <div class='slide'>2</div>
      <div class='slide'>3</div>
      <div class='slide'>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>5</div>
      <div class='slide'>6</div>
      <div class='slide'>7</div>
      <div class='slide'>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>2 slides per row</h2>
<div class='sliders' style='--slides-per-row: 2'>
  <div class='slider slider-main'>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>1</div>
      <div class='slide'>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>3</div>
      <div class='slide'>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>5</div>
      <div class='slide'>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>7</div>
      <div class='slide'>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='slider slider-copy'>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>1</div>
      <div class='slide'>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>3</div>
      <div class='slide'>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>5</div>
      <div class='slide'>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-row'>
      <div class='slide'>7</div>
      <div class='slide'>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your the best! Thanks a lot. Can't wait to use it to my code.